# Adobe Audience Manager External data

Tags: adobe

At my organization we are starting to use Adobe Audience Manager. We need to read online data from the website, but also to load data from our private database. Today, we do it by using the FTP, but it actually takes almost 3 days to load all the information so we can use it, which is a lot of time for us. I would like to know which is the best way or some alternatives so we can load information in a more agile and fast way, and ideally to read ir in the most real time possible from other sources (like our database or similar).

thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

AAM offline data can be uploaded either on an FTP location or to an AWS S3 bucket, and unfortunately both of them take from 12 to 24 hours to load on AAM (Adobe Audience Manager), and then it takes another 12 to 24 hours to load them into your DSP (Demand Side Platform).

Given that the only real-time like signals in AAM (that I know of) comes from the online datasources, the best way to achieve your requirement is to do the following:

1. Send as much information as possible from the online channel channel.
2. Build an integrate between your CRM data (database in your case) and the online data (user behaviour data on your website).

The CRM data should contain the user details that do not change much, such as demographics (age, gender, ...etc.), and it should also contain the data that are collected via the non-online channels (e.g. retail purchases, customer service phone calls, ...etc.). On the other hand, the online data should contain all the user behaviour data, collected from the online channel. For example, the user search parameters, visited page names, purchased items, clicked links, …etc.

The integration between the online and CRM data can be done by using the same user ID in both activities. The following diagram should give you a high level view of integration. [Simple AAM diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weRxP.png)

Here is an example of passing the user ID and online behavior data to AAM

```js
var user_id = "<add your website user ID here>";//ex: user1234

//Add all your online data here
var my_object = {
   color : "blue",
   price : "900",
   page_name : "cart details"
};

//Create the Dil object
var adobe_dil = DIL.create({
 partner : "<partner name goes here>",
 declaredId : {
   dpid : '<add your online data source ID here>' ,
   dpuuid : user_id
 }});

//Load the object and append "c_" to all keys in the key-value pairs and send data to AudienceManager.
adobe_dil.api.signals(my_object,"c_").submit();
```

And here is an example of the offline data upload

```js
user1234 "age_range"="1","gender"="F","city"="LA","status"="active"
user5678 "age_range"="2","gender"="M","city"="CA","status"="inactive"
```

Another Idea, which I haven't done before and I don't really recommend, is to send all your CRM data as online transactions, by calling the online API directly from your back-end. It may cost you more though, given the number of activities you will make to AAM from the back-end.

References:

- https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/aam/c_dil_send_page_objects.html
- https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/aam/r_dil_create.html